# Formulario dinámico para editar, borrar y añadir nuevos registros mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estoy intentando insertar, editar y borrar valores de dos tablas relacionadas

tabla viajes

| idviaje | cliente | referencia_cliente | ordendecarga | nombrecon_1 |telefonocon_1 |mailcon_1 |

tabla contactosviajes

|idcontactosviajes |idviaje| nombrecon |telefonocon | mailcon |

El código que tengo hasta ahora presenta los siguientes fallos:

1.- El scrip que se permite clonar los "div" para la inserción de más contactos funciona perfectamente en el archivo crearviaje.php , pero en el archivo editarviaje.php no. No encuentro la manera de traspasar el valor de "$no" a la "var = contador" para que así el script tenga en cuenta cuantos contactos ya hay creados.
No solo hace falta traspasar esa variable ya que lo he hecho "manualmente" y aunque así el valor de "contador" inicial es correcto clona div de más. Si hay 2 div agrega 2 div extra, si hay 3 div añade 3 div extra......

2.- Al eliminar uno de los contactos mediante el archivo deletecontactoviaje.php no soy capaz de re direccionar al archivo editarviaje.php con el id que estaba editando. No consigo extraer el valor del "idviaje"

3.- No se como plantear cuando en un viaje ya creado se intente añadir un nuevo contacto. 
De la manera que tengo ahora planteado el código solo se puede editar 3 contactos, el de la tabla viajes y 2 de la tabla contactosviajes.
Si se crea un viaje con dos contactos, el de la primera  y  segunda tabla y luego se intenta añadir el tercero como debería escribir el código para que diferencie cuando debe ejecutar INSERT o UPDATE?

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda

editarviaje.php

```
<?php

require('db.php');
$idviaje=$_REQUEST['idviaje'];
$query = "SELECT * from viajes where idviaje='".$idviaje."'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die ( mysqli_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>

<?php

require('db.php');
$idviaje=$_REQUEST['idviaje'];
$query2 = "SELECT * from contactosviajes where idviaje='".$idviaje."'"; 
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, $query2) or die ( mysqli_error());
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
$query = mysqli_query($con, $query2);
?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

            <title>Webslesson Demo - Dynamically Add or Remove input fields in PHP with JQuery</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <link href='jquery-ui.min.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' >
            <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <meta charset="utf-8">


</head>
<body>
            <div class="form">
            <?php
            $status = "";
            if(isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new']==1)
            {
            $idviaje=$_REQUEST['idviaje'];
            $cliente =$_REQUEST['cliente'];
            $nombrecon_1 =$_REQUEST['nombrecon_1'];
            $referencia_cliente =$_REQUEST['referencia_cliente'];
            $telefonocon_1 =$_REQUEST['telefonocon_1'];
            $mailcon_1 =$_REQUEST['mailcon_1'];
            $update="update viajes set cliente='".$cliente."', referencia_cliente='".$referencia_cliente."', nombrecon_1='".$nombrecon_1."', telefonocon_1='".$telefonocon_1."', mailcon_1='".$mailcon_1."' where idviaje='".$idviaje."'";
            mysqli_query($con, $update) or die(mysqli_error());

            $idcontactosviajes2=$_REQUEST['idcontactosviajes_2'];
            $nombrecon =$_REQUEST['nombrecon_2'];
            $telefonocon =$_REQUEST['telefonocon_2'];
            $mailcon =$_REQUEST['mailcon_2'];
            $update="update contactosviajes set nombrecon='".$nombrecon."', telefonocon='".$telefonocon."', mailcon='".$mailcon."' where idcontactosviajes='".$idcontactosviajes2."'";
            mysqli_query($con, $update) or die(mysqli_error());

            $idcontactosviajes3=$_REQUEST['idcontactosviajes_3'];
            $nombrecon =$_REQUEST['nombrecon_3'];
            $telefonocon =$_REQUEST['telefonocon_3'];
            $mailcon =$_REQUEST['mailcon_3'];
            $update="update contactosviajes set nombrecon='".$nombrecon."', telefonocon='".$telefonocon."', mailcon='".$mailcon."' where idcontactosviajes='".$idcontactosviajes3."'";
            mysqli_query($con, $update) or die(mysqli_error());
            header("Location: index.php");  
            }else {
            ?>
            <div>


                <div class="container">
                <br />
                <br />
                <h2 align="center"><a href="http://www.webslesson.info/2016/02/dynamically-add-remove-input-fields-in-php-with-jquery-ajax.html" title="Dynamically Add or Remove input fields in PHP with JQuery">Dynamically Add or Remove input fields in PHP with JQuery</a></h2><br />
                <form name="form" method="post" action=""> 
                <input type="hidden" name="new" value="1" />
                <input name="idviaje" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['idviaje'];?>" />
                            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_fieldcli">

                                <td colspan="3" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF" bgcolor="#00CCFF"><b>DATOS DEL CLIENTE</b></td>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    <div   class="col-xs-4">
                                        <label for="ex1">Cliente</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" name="cliente" placeholder="Enter your Name" id='cliente' type="text" value="<?php echo $row['cliente'];?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div   class="col-xs-5">
                                        <label for="ex1">Referencia Facturación </label>
                                        <input class="form-control" name="referencia_cliente" placeholder="Introduce la referencía de facturación" id='referencia_cliente' type="text" value="<?php echo $row['referencia_cliente'];?>">
                                    </div>                         
                                    <div   class="col-xs-3">
                                        <label for="ex1">Orden de carga</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" name="ordendecarga" placeholder="Sube la orden de carga" id='ordendecarga' type="file">
                                    </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>




                <div class="lista2" type="hidden">

                    <div class="group" id="1">
                        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_fieldcli">

                            <td>
                            <div  class="col-xs-3">
                                <label for="ex1">Contacto</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="nombrecon_1" id="nombrecon_1" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['nombrecon_1'];?>">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <label for="ex2">Teléfono</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="telefonocon_1" id="telefonocon_1" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['telefonocon_1'];?>">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-5">
                                <label for="ex3">Mail</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="mailcon_1" id="mailcon_1" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['mailcon_1'];?>">
                            </div>
                            <a href="#" data-id="1" onClick="agrega()" class="btn btn-success">+</a>
                            </td>

                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>



            <?php } ?>


            <?php
            $no     = 2;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
            {
                echo '

                        <div class="lista2" type="hidden">

                            <div class="group" id="'.$no.'">
                                <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_fieldcli">

                                    <td>
                                    <input name="idcontactosviajes_'.$no.'" id="idcontactosviajes_'.$no.'" type="hidden" value="'.$row['idcontactosviajes'].'" />
                                    <div  class="col-xs-3">
                                        <label for="ex1">Contacto</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" name="nombrecon_'.$no.'" id="nombrecon_'.$no.'" type="text" value="'.$row['nombrecon'].'">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <label for="ex2">Teléfono</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" name="telefonocon_'.$no.'" id="telefonocon_'.$no.'" type="text" value="'.$row['telefonocon'].'">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                                        <label for="ex3">Mail</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" name="mailcon_'.$no.'" id="mailcon_'.$no.'" type="text" value="'.$row['mailcon'].'">
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="deletecontactoviaje.php?idcontactosviajes='.$row['idcontactosviajes'].'" onClick="elimina('.$no.')" data-id="'.$no.'" class="del">Eliminar</a>
                                    </td>

                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>';


                    $no++;





            }?>

                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>


</body>
</html>

        <script type="text/javascript">




            var contador = 1;

            function agrega(){
                contador = parseInt(contador) + 1;
                  var item = `<div class="group" id="`+contador+`">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_fieldcli">

                    <td>
                    <div   class="col-xs-3">
                        <label for="ex1">Contacto</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="nombrecon_`+contador+`" id="nombrecon_`+contador+`" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <label for="ex2">Teléfono</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="telefonocon_`+contador+`" id="telefonocon_`+contador+`" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                        <label for="ex3">Mail</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="mailcon_`+contador+`" id="mailcon_`+contador+`" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <button href="deletecontactoviaje.php" onClick="elimina(`+contador+`)" data-id="`+contador+`" class="del">Eliminar</button>
                    </td>

                </table>
            </div>`;
                    $(".lista2").append(item);
            }

            function elimina(x){
                $("div[id="+x+"]").remove();
              contador = 0;
              $(".lista2 .group").each(function(){
                contador = parseInt(contador) + 1;
                $(this).attr('id',contador)
                $(this).find('input.form-control').attr('id','nombrecon_'+contador+'')
                $(this).find('input.form-control').attr('name','nombrecon_'+contador+'')
                $(this).find('input.form-control').attr('id','telefonocon_'+contador+'')
                $(this).find('input.form-control').attr('id','mailcon_'+contador+'')
                $(this).find('input.form-control').attr('name','telefonocon_'+contador+'')
                $(this).find('input.form-control').attr('name','mailcon_'+contador+'')
                $(this).find('button.del').attr('data-id',contador)
                $(this).find('button.del').attr('onClick','elimina('+contador+')')
              })
            }


        </script>
```

deletecontactoviaje.php

```
<?php


    require('db.php');
    $id=$_REQUEST['idcontactosviajes'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM contactosviajes WHERE idcontactosviajes=$id"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die ( mysqli_error());
    $idviaje=$_REQUEST['idviaje'];

    $query = "DELETE FROM contactosviajes WHERE idcontactosviajes=$id"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die ( mysqli_error());


    header("Location: edit.php?idviaje=$idviaje"); 
    ?>
```

crearviaje.php

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Webslesson Demo - Dynamically Add or Remove input fields in PHP with JQuery</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <link href='jquery-ui.min.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' >
            <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <meta charset="utf-8">

        </head>
        <body>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



            <div class="container">
                <br />
                <br />
                <h2 align="center"><a href="http://www.webslesson.info/2016/02/dynamically-add-remove-input-fields-in-php-with-jquery-ajax.html" title="Dynamically Add or Remove input fields in PHP with JQuery">Dynamically Add or Remove input fields in PHP with JQuery</a></h2><br />
                <form action="data.php" method="POST">
                            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_fieldcli">

                                <td colspan="3" align="center" style="color:#FFFFFF" bgcolor="#00CCFF"><b>DATOS DEL CLIENTE</b></td>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    <div   class="col-xs-4">
                                        <label for="ex1">Cliente</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" name="nombrecli_1" placeholder="Enter your Name" id='nombrecli_1' type="text">
                                    </div>
                                    <div   class="col-xs-5">
                                        <label for="ex1">Referencia Facturación </label>
                                        <input class="form-control" name="referencia_cliente" placeholder="Introduce la referencía de facturación" id='referencia_cliente' type="text">
                                    </div>                         
                                    <div   class="col-xs-3">
                                        <label for="ex1">Orden de carga</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" name="ordendecarga" placeholder="Sube la orden de carga" id='ordendecarga' type="file">
                                    </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>




                <div class="lista2">

                    <div class="group" id="1">
                        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_fieldcli">

                            <td>
                            <div   class="col-xs-3">
                                <label for="ex1">Contacto</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="nombrecon_1" id="nombrecon_1" type="text">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <label for="ex2">Teléfono</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="telefonocon_1" id="telefonocon_1" type="text">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-5">
                                <label for="ex3">Mail</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="mailcon_1" id="mailcon_1" type="text">
                            </div>
                            <a href="#" data-id="1" onClick="agrega()" class="btn btn-success">+</a>
                            </td>

                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>

                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>



        </body>
    </html>

    <script type="text/javascript">




            var contador = 1;

            function agrega(){
                contador = parseInt(contador) + 1;
                  var item = `<div class="group" id="`+contador+`">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_fieldcli">

                    <td>
                    <div   class="col-xs-3">
                        <label for="ex1">Contacto</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="nombrecon_`+contador+`" id="nombrecon_`+contador+`" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <label for="ex2">Teléfono</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="telefonocon_`+contador+`" id="telefonocon_`+contador+`" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                        <label for="ex3">Mail</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="mailcon_`+contador+`" id="mailcon_`+contador+`" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <button onClick="elimina(`+contador+`)" data-id="`+contador+`" class="del">Eliminar</button>
                    </td>

                </table>
            </div>`;
                    $(".lista2").append(item);
            }

            function elimina(x){
                $("div[id="+x+"]").remove();
              contador = 0;
              $(".lista2 .group").each(function(){
                contador = parseInt(contador) + 1;
                $(this).attr('id',contador)
                $(this).find('input.form-control').attr('id','nombrecon_'+contador+'')
                $(this).find('input.form-control').attr('name','nombrecon_'+contador+'')
                $(this).find('input.form-control').attr('id','telefonocon_'+contador+'')
                $(this).find('input.form-control').attr('id','mailcon_'+contador+'')
                $(this).find('input.form-control').attr('name','telefonocon_'+contador+'')
                $(this).find('input.form-control').attr('name','mailcon_'+contador+'')
                $(this).find('button.del').attr('data-id',contador)
                $(this).find('button.del').attr('onClick','elimina('+contador+')')
              })
            }


        </script>
```

Comment: Porque no agregas `<?php if isset($row['nombrecon_2']) {?>` y asi agregar.  Similarmente asi harias con nombrecon_3

Comment: Lo primero que deberías hacer es normalizar las tablas de tu bd, mínimo, mínimo, mínimo a 1FN. https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primera_forma_normal  Lo adecuado para un mínimo aceptable sería 3FN.

Comment: Xerif, he tenido en cuenta tu comentario  y he re formulado la pregunta

Comment: @XavierVillafaina Me alegro de que resolvieras tu problema. no me di cuenta de tu comentario hasta ahora, cuando lo creas oportuno puedes utilizar la arroba seguido del nombre para mencionar a un usuario, y asi le llege un aviso. Un saludo.

Comment: @Xerif Gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 2):

He conseguido mostrar los valores de la tabla relacionada mediante el siguiente código.

Ahora solo me falta actuar sobre el script que permite clonar "div".

Muchas gracias Xerif, me ha resultado muy útil cambiar la estructura de la tabla.

```
    <?php

require('db.php');
$idviaje=$_REQUEST['idviaje'];
$query2 = "SELECT * from contactosviajes where idviaje='".$idviaje."'"; 
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, $query2) or die ( mysqli_error());
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
$query = mysqli_query($con, $query2);
?>



                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
            {
                echo '

                        <div class="lista2" type="hidden">

                            <div class="group" id="1">
                                <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_fieldcli">

                                    <td>
                                    <div  class="col-xs-3">
                                        <label for="ex1">Contacto</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" name="nombrecon_1" id="nombrecon_1" type="text" value="'.$row['nombrecon'].'">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <label for="ex2">Teléfono</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" name="telefonocon_1" id="telefonocon_1" type="text" value="'.$row['telefonocon'].'">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                                        <label for="ex3">Mail</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" name="mailcon_1" id="mailcon_1" type="text" value="'.$row['mailcon'].'">
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="#" data-id="1" onClick="agrega()" class="btn btn-success">+</a>
                                    </td>

                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>';





            }?>
```